# Unable to fetch Stream of Strings and pass it as a parameter to another method which returns int

Tags: java-8

```
public class JavaStreamMultIterator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    private void iterateStringList() {
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");

        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        intList = stringList
                .stream()
                .forEach(s - > {intForString(s));
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Integer intForString(String s) {

        switch (s) {
            case "one":
                return 1;
            case "two":
                return 2;
            case "three":
                return 3;
            default:
                return 15;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a `List<String>` and I want to iterate through this list, fetch the `String` and pass it as a parameter to method.

That method will return an `Integer` and I want to add it to a `List<Integer>`.

```
intList = stringList
            .stream()
            .forEach(s - > {intForString(s));
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You don't asked a question.

Comment: As an advice for the future, stop trying to use `forEach` for everything and start looking for an appropriate method for the task. E.g., by looking at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: I don't think this compiles. Btw, you can mark an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

forEach is terminal function, it would consume and does not return anything.
You need to value from intForString() for your list generation.

```
List<Integer> intList =
                stringList //your list
                .stream() //generate stream
                .map(this::intForString) //map them to integer 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());//collect all the integer toList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use `map`

```
stringList.stream()
            .map(s->intForString(s))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```